# Find the 3G band for Nexus One

Tags: android, 3g, nexus-one

Given a nexus one (rather any Android phone), is it a way to find out which 3g band it supports (t-mobile or att), without inserting any SIM cards ? currently I'm just interested in nexus one, but generic info can be useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Take off the back cover off the Nexus One, remove the battery and read the FCC ID number at the top of the black area.

The FCC # for the AT&T version is NM8PB99110

The FCC # for the T-Mobile  version is NM8PB99100

Comment: Is there a programatic way of telling the same ?